# Multiple select box ctrl+A not working in firefox

Tags: html

```
Name: <input type="text" name="check">
Car:  <select name="cars" multiple>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="opel">Opel</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>
```

When I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> all the select box values should selected in multiple select box.

When I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> it will select all the texts.

It's working in Google Chrome, but its not working in FireFox or IE9, IE10.

How do I add this option to multiple select box?

Comment: well its work for me... in Firefox

Comment: Please learn about formatting in SO using the [help pages provided](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).  Also, it's not clear exactly what you're asking for

Answer (score 2):

This post has a few years, but may still have someone in doubt. So here is the solution:

```
window.onkeydown = function(e) {
    /* If press Ctrl + "A" */
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 65) {
       /* Get all (<SELECT multiple>) elements on the page. */
       document.querySelectorAll("select[multiple]").forEach(function(select) {
           /* If the keys are pressed on the element... */
            if (e.target === select) {
                /* The e.preventDefault prevents all page text from being selected. */
                e.preventDefault();
                /* Now we get all the OPTIONS elements and set them as selected. */
                select.querySelectorAll('option').forEach(function(option) {
                    option.selected = true;
                });
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation for this code? Please describe how this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Give each element their own div. You don't even have to use CSS to size the divs, just throw a div around each. It will highlight each; just as if you were to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>.